# Pass core data to sub view

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to pass core data down to a sub/child view but I can't get it to work.

In my SingleView, I have:

```
struct CitySingleView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var city: Cities

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            HeaderView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)

            Text("\(city.name ?? "no name")") // <--- This works and prints the name

        }
    }

}
```

in my HeaderView, I have:

```
struct HeaderView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var city: Cities?

   .......

    var body: some View {

         Text("\(city?.name ?? "Not found")").font(.system(size: 36)) // <--- This doesn't work and prints "not found"              
    }

}
```

Do I have to pass the current city as an argument to the HeaderView, and if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

so, turns out I the argument I need to pass is city: city.... ;-)